# Issue with youtube upload using resumable c# code

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-client-login

When I try to upload a video to the you tube using resumable upload using the code in C# . 
I am getting an error message "The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.".

Here is the code that we use to upload the video using C#.

```
var credentials = new GDataCredentials(_account, _password);

_authenticator = new ClientLoginAuthenticator("YouTubeUploader", ServiceNames.YouTube, credentials){DeveloperKey = _developerKey};
_resumableUploader = new ResumableUploader();

_resumableUploader.AsyncOperationCompleted += new AsyncOperationCompletedEventHandler(UlAsyncOperationCompleted);
_resumableUploader.AsyncOperationProgress += new AsyncOperationProgressEventHandler(UlAsyncOperationProgress);

var v = new Video
                        {
                            Title = "some title",
                            Description = "some description",
                            Keywords = "list of keywords separated by comma",
                            Private = false
                        };
            v.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Entertainment"));

            string contentType = MediaFileSource.GetContentTypeForFileName("Video file name");
            v.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource("video file name", contentType);

            // add the upload uri to it
            var link =
                new AtomLink("http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/" + Account + "/uploads")
                    {Rel = ResumableUploader.CreateMediaRelation};

            v.YouTubeEntry.Links.Add(link);
              XmlExtension unlistedAccessControlXmlExtension = CreateAccessControlXmlExtension("list", "denied");
            XmlExtension noCommentAccessControlXmlExtension = CreateAccessControlXmlExtension("comment", "denied");
            XmlExtension rat1 = CreateAccessControlXmlExtension("commentVote", "denied");
            XmlExtension rat2 = CreateAccessControlXmlExtension("videoRespond", "denied");
            XmlExtension rat3 = CreateAccessControlXmlExtension("rate", "denied");

            v.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(rat1);
            v.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(rat2);
            v.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(rat3);

            v.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(unlistedAccessControlXmlExtension);
            v.YouTubeEntry.ExtensionElements.Add(noCommentAccessControlXmlExtension);

            var info = new YouTubeFileInfo(desc.Id) { Status = YouTubeFileInfo.YouTubeFileStatus.Uploading, FileName = fileName };

            _resumableUploader.InsertAsync(_authenticator, v.YouTubeEntry, data);
```

I think we are facing the issue because of change in the upload URL Version 2 to version 3. 
I suspect we should no longer use "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/resumable/feeds/api/users/" + Account + "/uploads"

Can you please help me provide an information regarding how to do the change code or the New URL for Version 3.
So that the video Uploads will be successful using the resumable uploads of Version 3.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to login using a login and password which doesn't work anymore.  You either need to change it to OAuth2, I would also recommend you upgrade to the current version of the YouTube API.

**Using Google .net client library**

[PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.YouTube.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.youtube.v3/)

**Using Oauth2 with YouTube API v3.**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

                YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Data API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

        }
```

code ripped from [youtube sample project](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/YouTube)

Comment: After your suggestion regarding the login version, I tried to migrate from Version 2 to version 3. Got the  clientID , API Id, SecretID of my account. Added the same to the code. But getting the Error

400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
Application: YouTubeUpload
You can email the developer of this application at: XXXXXXX@gmail.com
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:2340/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI.

Comment: set redirect uri to localhost/authorize while debugging localhost or use a native one instead of a web application one.   remove your client id from the last comment. You need to keep that safe.